# iOS: How do I save an NSURL in an SQLite database?

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have a schema like this

```
CREATE TABLE table(_id integer primary key, orig_url text, new_url text)
```

and I want to save `NSURL`s – or their string representation – in this database. Assume I have strings like this:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=F658E5E1-6449-4674-85B5-2F2EC3C72A00&ext=JPG
```

The trouble is, I know little of SQL or sqlite and the URLs include characters which must be escaped, otherwise I get

```
unrecognized token: ":"
```

I could replace the problematic chars manually, but I'd like a solution which does proper SQL escaping.

What is the most straightforward way to insert such strings into the database and get them out unescaped?

Comment: Insert: `NSURL` -> `NSString` -> `const char *`. Fetch: `const char *` -> `NSString` -> `NSURL`.

Comment: The question is about escaping the special characters (see edit), not the trivial conversion.

Comment: Use bind variables; no escaping is required.